# Passing Argument To Rake Dependency

Tags: ruby, rake

I understand how to pass an argument to rake task, but I can't work out how to pass an argument to a dependent task.

I have a task that just runs a list of dependent tasks:

```
task foo [:alpha, :bravo, :charlie, :delta]
```

I need to add a task called `:omega`:

```
task foo [:omega, :alpha, :bravo, :charlie, :delta]
```

But I need to pass a parameter to it. I don't want to pass the parameter in to :foo - I just want to hardcode the parameter into the dependent task. I want to do this (I know it isn't valid):

```
task foo [:omega('Some Param'), :alpha, :bravo, :charlie, :delta]
```

How do I pass in the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Rake will run all the "dependent" tasks before running your task...so I doubt you will be able to achieve the above

Can you explain further what you are trying to achieve?

Jusy as an example if the task is run from the command line you may be able to do the following

```
rake foo omegaVar
```

In you code

```
def confirmDestruction
    print "Are you sure you want to do that?\n"
    answer=gets()
    if answer == 'y'
      return true
    else
      exit 0
    end
end

task :omega do
   $conrimedDestruction = confirmDestruction if $conrimedDestruction.nil?
   if $conrimedDestruction
     print "${$omegaVar}\n"
   else
     print "non destructive functionality\n"
   end
end

task :alpha do
   if $conrimedDestruction
     print "${$omegaVar}\n"
   else
     print "non destructive functionality\n"
   end
end
task :foo => [:omega, :alpha, :bravo, :charlie, :delta]
```

Comment: I have a simple task that is a confirmation step - The user types y to confirm and if they type anything else rake quits. I use this task in multiple places but at the moment, the message is a generic 'Confirm destructive action'. I would like a way to pass in the message each time I use it so that it is specific to the place it is used.

Comment: If i were implementing this I would create a function/method instead of a task for the confirmation. Call the function/method every time you want to confirm. If you set a global variable, then you could set it once, all tasks could cckeck to see if the confirm function has been called, if not call it else run the destructive task Then have a function that can clear the global variable.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? How would that work with a task like: `task foo [:alpha, :bravo, :charlie, :delta]`

Comment: @Pedr I have updated the same code above to give an example

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse, that is not possible. The available options are:

```
task :t do
task :t, :a, :b, ... do
task :t, [:a, :b, ...] do
```

if you [don't specify](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v12.3.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb#L106-L112) dependencies. And:

```
task :t => [:d1, d2, ...] do
task :t, [:a, :b, ...] => [:d1, d2, ...] do
```

if [you do](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v12.3.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb#L126-L137).

Unless you want to invoke it manually:

```
task :a, :p do |task, args|
  puts "p: #{args[:p]}"
end
task :b do
  Rake::Task[:a].invoke(1)
end
```

```
$ rake b
p: 1
```